# Where is Mike Lesk's (circa 1973) "portable I/O package" for C?

Tags: c, reference-request, io

According to Dennis Ritchie's 1993 paper *[The Development of the C Language](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.pdf)*:

> Also during this period, the compiler was retargeted to other nearby machines, particularly the Honeywell 635 and IBM 360/370; because the language could not live in isolation, the prototypes for the modern libraries were developed. In particular, Lesk wrote a ‘portable I/O package’ [Lesk 72] that was later reworked to become the C ‘standard I/O’ routines.

The reference `[Lesk 72]` may be an error, since it is given in the references section as `[Lesk 73]`:

> M. E. Lesk, ‘A Portable I/O Package,’ AT&T Bell Laboratories internal memorandum ca. 1973.

I cannot find any copy of this memorandum anywhere; given it was an "internal memorandum", I assume it is not publicly available (if it survives at all). But, I am wondering, in its absence, if there are any public sources on the details of Lesk's package, and how it differed from later `<stdio.h>`?

Comment: If nobody here turns up a copy, you might try asking Michael Lesk directly.  His e-mail address is on [his home page](https://www.lesk.com/mlesk/).

Comment: The updated 1975 version of the memo is here: [The Portable C Library](https://archive.org/details/ThePortableCLibrary_May75/page/n1/mode/2up)

Comment: @scruss you should post that as an answer

Comment: @SimonKissane Clem Cole's answer is just as good, and came in before my comment

Comment: @scruss The 1975 version of the memo is more interesting (to me at least) because it includes all the details of the GCOS and OS/360 implementations. The one from the V6 Unix sources omits all that.

Comment: It's totally okay to answer your own question with the document I provided: I don't play this site for brownie points

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unless you are an old guy like me, you'll need to run this thru groff -ms unless you know how to decode troff

[Mike Lesk's Portable I/O Library](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/doc/iolib/iolib)

Comment: and for those who tire of dot commands, I ran it through groff: [The Portable C Library (on UNIX)](https://archive.org/details/lesk-iolib)